# FMDB and LIKE clause

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, parameters, fmdb

I'm having trouble getting the FMDB wrapper for iOS to work with a parameter and a LIKE clause. In fact I'm having trouble getting the LIKE clause to work at all on SQLite with FMDB.

I've tried using `Name LIKE '%dam%' to match "Adam", and I've tried specifying it as a parameter as below, but none works.

```
    [buffer appendString:@" Name LIKE '%dam%' "]; // no results

    [buffer appendString:@" Name LIKE ? "];
    [params addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", args.name]]; // no results

    [buffer appendString:@" Name LIKE '%' ? '%' "];
    [params addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", args.name]]; // no results
```

There are definitely items in the table which match the criteria, I just can't see why FMDB isn't returning them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had this head ache one day too. try this

```
[buffer appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Name LIKE '%@dam%@' ",@"%",@"%"];
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no easy way to escape parameters with SQLite. It's not a specific FMDB issue. Your code won't really do anything to prevent SQL injection though.

Comment: if you want answers on sqlite injection - post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the regular SQL query to pull the data to a FMResultset.  This worked fine for me.

If you need to filter the data later on, use NSPredicate which works great.

[NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) docs

```
predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"authors.lastName CONTAINS %@", @"Mark" ];
filtered  = [bookshelf filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: I've heard bad opinions of predictates in objective-c. This database also typically contains anywhere up to 10000 items, and I need to page the results to 30 records at a time, so this won't work. I'd prefer to get it working with FMDB really, as it should be possible.